# PHPExcel - my autodetecter for CSV : Can I access the orig uploaded file before it's parsed?

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I'm hoping to find some PHPExcel users here because activity in their discussion groups seems a bit on the leisurely side :). (My orig post there [**can be seen here**](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/362816))

I scratched together a function for autodetecting delimiters and/or enclosures for CSV files.
Now that it's running, I'd like to plug it into PHPExcel (by extending the CSV class).
My only problem is that my OOP skills are pretty young, and I'm having a little trouble finding how/where to integrate it.

My function currently takes an array created via `file()`, but I can change that easily if needed.

```
function autoDetect(array $file, array $toDetect=array(true,false), $sampleSize=5){  

    $detectDelim = $toDetect[0]? true: false;
    $detectEncl = $toDetect[1]? true: false; 
    $sampleSize = ( count($file) < $sampleSize)? count($file): $sampleSize;  // set sample-size to the lesser value    
    array_splice($file, $sampleSize);  // trim down the array to only first X rows

    $delimiters = array(',','^','.',';',':',"\t"); // first elem will be the dflt
    $delimRegex = implode('',$delimiters);

    $enclosures = array('"',"'",'^'); // first elem will be the dflt
    $enclRegex = implode('',$enclosures);

    foreach ($file as $row) {
        $row=preg_replace( '/\r\n/', '', trim($row) );  // clean up .. strip new line and line return chars

        if($detectDelim){
            $stripped=preg_replace( "/[^$delimRegex]/", '', $row);  // clean up .. strip evthg x'ept dilim's
            $delimRowChars = str_split($stripped);  // get each char so we can inspect individually
            $delimCount = _count_instances($delimRowChars, $delimiters);  // TODO : fix how this overwrites itself
            // TODO : set delim
        }

        if($detectEncl){
            $stripped=preg_replace( "/[^$enclRegex]/", '', $row);  // clean up .. strip evthg x'ept dilim's
            $enclRowChars = str_split($stripped);  // get each char so we can inspect individually
            $enclCount = _count_instances($enclRowChars, $enclosures);  // TODO : fix how this overwrites itself
            // TODO : set encl
        }
    }

    echo'<pre>delims found in sample set: ', print_r($delimCount), '</pre>';  // For Testing ---->
    echo'<pre>encls found in sample set: ', print_r($enclCount), '</pre>';  // For Testing ---->
    echo "<pre>Suggested Delimiter: '",_array_max($delimCount),"' </pre>";  // For Testing ---->    
    echo "<pre>Suggested Enclosure: '",_array_max($enclCount),"' </pre>";  // For Testing ---->

    //return TODO ;        
}


/**
 * 
 */
function _count_instances(array $haystacks, array $needles, $maxOnly = false){
    $basket = array();  // instantiate
    foreach ($haystacks as $haystack) {
        foreach ($needles as $needle) {  // this throws an undef'd index err and adds an element to the array
            if( strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {  // if the needle is in the haystack ...
                if($needle == "\t") $needle = '\t';  // TODO : decouple this from "\t" so it can work for other chars too
                $basket[$needle]++;  // ... increment
            }
        }
    }
    if($maxOnly) $basket = _array_max($basket);
    return $basket;
}

/**
 * 
 */
function _array_max(array $target){
    $target = array_keys($target, max($target));
    $target = $target[0];
    return $target;
}
```

I just need to run my auto detector prior to the file getting parsed, and I'm not seeing the info in the object.
When/where/how should it get plugged in?
Is there access to the orig file, or ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHPExcel community did end up providing a response, so I thought I'd shahre it here for posterity sake :)
It can also be seen via the link provided toward the top of the OP.

> "You'd need to put the call to this autodetector in the
>   loadIntoExisting method of the PHPExcel/Reader/CSV.php file; but the
>   script reads the CSV a line at a time rather than loading every line
>   into memory (we have enough memory issues without deliberately trying
>   to create them). Logically, you'd probably want to load up just a few
>   lines immediately after the check for the BOM, set the
>   $this->_delimiter value, and then remember to rewind the file
>   afterwards."

Hope it can help someone else.